# How to create and start the emulator using Jenkins

Tags: android, docker, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, kvm

I am new to the docker and Jenkins. First i create the docker image file. In that image install sdk and start the emulator. when i am start the emulator i am getting a following  error.

Here is my code

```
FROM openjdk:8
# Install Git and dependencies
RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y file git curl zip libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 \
 && apt-get clean \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists /var/cache/apt

# Set up environment variables

ENV ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk" \
    SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip" \
    GRADLE_URL="https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-all.zip"

# Create a non-root user

RUN chmod 777 -Rf /opt

# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
 && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
 && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
 && unzip sdk.zip \
 && rm sdk.zip \
 && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
RUN chmod 777 -Rf /opt/*
# Install Gradle
RUN wget $GRADLE_URL -O gradle.zip \
 && unzip gradle.zip \
 && mv gradle-4.5.1 gradle \
 && rm gradle.zip \
 && mkdir .gradle

ENV PATH="/home/user/gradle/bin:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:${PATH}"

RUN echo y | android update sdk --no-ui
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-19.0.3
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-25.0.3
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-26.0.2
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-27.0.3
RUN echo y | android update sdk --filter tools,platform-tools,build-tools-28.0.1
RUN cd /opt/android-sdk/ && mkdir platforms
RUN cd /opt/android-sdk/tools/bin && ./sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" && echo y | ./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" -b x86 -c 100M -d 7 -f
```

[Here is my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEZZA.png)

Comment: It says VT is not enabled. Is this the error you are talking about? If so, you need to enable virtualization on your BIOS.

Comment: i was virtualization option in BIOS setup. That option is already enabled.

Comment: When I had this specific error, I enabled VTx at the BIOS. Don't know if something else is needed in your case...

Comment: now i am facing this error
Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: This user doesn't have permissions to use KVM (/dev/kvm)

Comment: This is more complicated. Never saw this error. Please check my Docker Android to see if you might find something useful: https://github.com/lovato/docker-android

Comment: If I running the emulator on the host machine using cli working fine. but i am running a emulator in jenkins i got a erro like kvm issue

Comment: in your Github repository, there is no create or run emulator command. can you guide me?

Comment: I haven't done it yet... in my life. As soon as I know how to do it, I would be able to help you out.